# How to group the roads into certain areas

Tags: java, geocoding, geospatial

I have four latitude and longitude points which forms a rectangle(area).Now I want to divide the rectangle into grids.I also have the end and start latitude and longitude values of all the roads in the area.So now I want to basically group the roads into the grids and find each grid and the set of roads they have:

So I define the latlong 
`(11.20804, 122.22839),(11.20804, 122.52914),(11.06926, 122.52914),(11.06926,  122.22839)`
 
which are the latitude longitude (respectively) of the rectangle.I also have the methods

```
road(i).get_start_latlong().toString();
road(i).get_end_latlong().toString();
```

which gives the end and start latitude and longitude values like

```
   12.8797, 121.7740
   12.8317, 121.7340
```

So I want each grid to be 10m*10 m.So I planned to check if the end or start of the road falls into the grid then it is added to the set of roads in the grid.

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
   double s=Double.parseDouble(road(i).get_start_latlong().toString());
   double e=Double.parseDouble(road(i).get_end_latlong().toString());  


   //Here I have to check either s or e falls into which grid id 
   //For example if road_id 10 falls into grid_id 1 then add the road_id 10                   in the list of grid_id 1
}
```

I want to group my grids with their roads.
Finally I should have something like

```
grid_id         road_id
_______        __________ 
   1            10,12,18
   2            19,1,9
   3            1,2,8
   4            24,26,27
....
..
...
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the grids you will have to find a numerical value of the area of the of the rectangle and then divide that into grids from that and assign each grid to a variable in order to display that grid.

The toString() method should only be used to show the values stored not to make the grid system.

Comment: What do you mean by `to find a numerical value of the area`?Can you explain more clear if you don't mind

Comment: You cant find the value of an area using a toString. Convert your string to a type double by using, Double.parsedouble(stringName), then create a rectangle object getting its width and length from your lat/long values you converted and with those values you can get an complete area of the rectangle and create a loop to create the grid for the rectangle. If you can tell me what you need as an output or you overall goal I will be able to help you further.

Comment: Ya I understand that I need to convert string to a type double but I am struggling to create the grid for the rectangle and then group all the roads into the grids.Like say the grid_id and its group of roads which it contains

Comment: Could you help me?